# Create power point file in asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office, powerpoint

I have one diagram generated on aspx page,  I want to download that page in power point format in browser. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You have a diagram that you want to save it as a power point document? Or something else?

Comment: What kind diagram you have (format? picture?) And you want to generate a power point document and let user to download it?

Comment: Yeah.. I have a diagram of employee hierarchy which contains squares and lines for the linking between employees and individual square contains picture of employee and its basic info.

Comment: When user clicks on download button I'm creating above mentioned diagram (in my above comment) on aspx page and now next task is I want to download that page in ppt format. Here I'm not showing that generated diagram to user I just want to download generated aspx page in browser in power point format.